# Parameter 'targetingCriteria' is invalid for audience count with LinkedIn marketing API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I was trying to get audience count by using targetingCriteriaV2 by Curl and Guzzle request but its showing as targetingCriteria is invalid.

API url 1:

**https://api.linkedin.com/v2/audienceCountsV2?q=targetingCriteriaV2&targetingCriteria=(include:(and:List((or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3Alocations:List(urn%3Ali%3AcountryGroup%3Ana))),(or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3Askills:List(urn%3Ali%3Askill%3A17))))))**

API url 2:

**https://api.linkedin.com/v2/audienceCountsV2?q=targetingCriteriaV2&targetingCriteria=(include:(and:List((or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3AjobFunctionsList(urn%3Ali%3Afunction%3A1,urn%3Ali%3Afunction%3A8,urn%3Ali%3Afunction%3A5))))))**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the `X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0` as the header in your API requests, as example:

```
curl \
   -H "Authorization:Bearer <the-token>" \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -H "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" \
   "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/audienceCountsV2?q=targetingCriteriaV2&targetingCriteria=(include:(and:List((or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3Alocations:List(urn%3Ali%3AcountryGroup%3Ana))),(or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3Askills:List(urn%3Ali%3Askill%3A17))))))"
```

There are also two other problems with your api calls:

The first API use a [legacy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/bing-geo-migration-guide) geo locations: `urn:li:countryGroup:na` you should use BING geo locations. As example for North America you should use `urn:li:geo:102221843` and the API call will success like:

```
curl \
   -H "Authorization:Bearer <the token>" \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -H "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" \
   "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/audienceCountsV2?q=targetingCriteriaV2&targetingCriteria=(include:(and:List((or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3Alocations:List(urn%3Ali%3Ageo%3A102221843))),(or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3Askills:List(urn%3Ali%3Askill%3A17))))))"

{"paging":{"start":0,"count":10,"links":[]},"elements":[{"active":0,"total":2900000}]}%
```

The second API call seems malformed, yes a very strange format for targeting locations !!!!